# nvidia-smi: GPU's full name not displayed properly

Tags: linux, gpu, nvidia

On a Linux server, `nvidia-smi` can show GPU name, as well as other useful information. However, the full name is not displayed properly. How can I know the full name of GPUs?

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> How can I know the full name of GPUs?

```
$ nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (UUID: GPU-c68bc30d-90ca-0087-6b5e-39aea8767b58)
```

or

```
$ nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv
name
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
```

Before asking, I encourage trying first finding the answer yourself. Both `man nvidia-smi` and `nvidia-smi -h` list many options. Also try google https://www.google.com/search?q=nvidia-smi+display+name -> [https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3751/~/useful-nvidia-smi-queries](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3751/%7E/useful-nvidia-smi-queries) .

Comment: Is it possible to set the name?